# MongoDB C# Driver Update Document with Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

As described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-with-aggregation-pipeline) from **MongoDB 4.2** on it is possible to **update documents with an aggregation pipeline**.

It means that now it is possible to express "conditional updates based on current field values or **updating one field using the value of another field(s)**".

For instance:

```
db.members.update(
   { },
   [
      { $set: { status: "Modified", comments: [ "$misc1", "$misc2" ], lastUpdate: "$$NOW" } },
      { $unset: [ "misc1", "misc2" ] }
   ],
   { multi: true }
)
```

My question is: how can I do this using **MongoDB on C#**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IMongoCollection`'s UpdateMany takes `UpdateDefinition<T>` as second parameter and [PipelineUpdateDefinition](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/841984a996eb17023feacd8b0b8da02a564bad8e/src/MongoDB.Driver/UpdateDefinition.cs#L92) is one of the derived classes. There's no expression trees support so far but you can utilize `BsonDocument` class:

```
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> col = ...;
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<BsonDocument>()
                    .AppendStage("{ $addFields : { " +
                                        "status : 'Modified'," +
                                        "comments: [ '$misc1', '$misc2' ]," +
                                        "lastUpdate: '$$NOW' " +
                                    "} }",
                        BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance)
                    .AppendStage("{ $project : { 'misc1':0, 'misc2':0 } }",
                    BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance);

col.UpdateMany(new BsonDocument(), pipeline);
```

which executes following command (trace from MongoDB driver):

```
"updates" : [
    { 
        "q" : { }, 
        "u" : [
            { "$addFields" : { "status" : "Modified", "comments" : ["$misc1", "$misc2"], "lastUpdate" : "$$NOW" } }, 
            { "$project" : { "misc1" : 0, "misc2" : 0 } }], 
        "multi" : true }
    }
]
```

Comment: Sounds perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't work for the latest C# driver. Compile errors all over the place :(